# How do I make WPF ListView items repeat horizontally AND vertically?

Tags: wpf, templates, xaml, listview

I have a `ListView` where I would like to display things horizontally. That works fine, but now I would need to have them display like in a Windows Explorer type.

For example :

```
A   B   C

D   E   F

G   H   I
```

or

```
A   B

C   D

E   F

G   H

I
```

Is it possible in a `ListView`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want your items to all have the same size, I would go for a [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx). It one of those overlooked controls, might be very useful in this situation.

This is how I made a quick-and-dirty toolbar:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding}"
                    ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Image Height="16"
                           Width="16"
                           RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
                           Source="{Binding Image}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Cool. That worked. However, I already changed to two listview since it was rather urgent. Nevertheless, I will remember the uniform grid as my tests were rather conclusives.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you're looking for WrapPanel.  I don't think it works for ListView, but if you want a generic items container to use WrapPanel as it's layout, you can do this with ItemsControl and fill it with whatever elements you want.  Something like the following:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <TextBlock Margin="20" Padding="20" Text="Blah" Background="#999" />
        <TextBlock Margin="20" Padding="20" Text="Blah" Background="#999" />
        <TextBlock Margin="20" Padding="20" Text="Blah" Background="#999" />
        <TextBlock Margin="20" Padding="20" Text="Blah" Background="#999" />
        <TextBlock Margin="20" Padding="20" Text="Blah" Background="#999" />
        <TextBlock Margin="20" Padding="20" Text="Blah" Background="#999" />
    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Like you said it doesn't seem to work with WrapPanel, but what I will do is have two list that are on top of one another, since I know the exact number of max item I will have.

Comment: You can get this to work with ListView.  I've done it, but don't have the code handy at the moment.  Do some Google searches, and you'll find it.

Comment: Does it "have" to be a ListView?  WPF is so flexible, that you can get a lot of the same list displaying functionality out of a number of different containers.  The container isn't usually the functionality you're looking for, it's the templates (ItemsTemplate, ItemsPanelTemplate).